# Кто может отредактировать страницу "Тур"?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

На данный момент, на странице [Тур](https://rus.stackexchange.com/tour) красуется следующая надпись про офф-топик:

```
Не задавайте вопросы…
Все, что не связано напрямую с русский язык
```

Очевидно, корректный вариант такой:

```
Не задавайте вопросы…
Все, что не связано напрямую с русским языком
```

Или даже такой:

```
Не задавайте…
Вопросы, не связанные напрямую с русским языком
```

Не могли бы модераторы исправить данный текст?
Также буду рад информации о том, куда сообщать о необходимости подобных исправлений в будущем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Поправил.

Comment: Поправьте ещё и предыдущий блок текста, "Спрашивайте о...", там тоже "русский язык" остался в именительном. Сразу не заметил, виноват :)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Готово!

Answer (score 2):

В данный момент на сайте «Русский язык» это может сделать только менеджер сообщества [Николай Чабановский](http://%20https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2/nicolas-chabanovsky).

Большая часть строк в интерфейсе сайтов (кроме справки и ещё нескольких страниц) общая для сайтов «Русский язык» и «Stack Overflow на русском». Однако на Мете Русского языка (т.е. здесь) довольно-таки тихо.

Поэтому о всех ошибках на этом сайте лучше сообщать на [Мету Stack Overflow на русском](http://%20https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Там есть десяток активных переводчиков и полсотни просто активных участников. В простых случаях на исправление ошибки уходит не более суток.

Подробнее: [Коллективный перевод сайта сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/181472)